# How do I compile a Java application that uses Apache Commons IO at the command line

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, compiler-errors, apache-commons

I made an application in NetBeans and I used the Apache Commons IO jar file.  The application works fine in NetBeans, but I want to be able to compile it from the command line.  The Apache Commons IO jar is with my *.java files but I get a commpiler error that says package org.apache.commons.io does not exist.

Comment: Please provide command you ran and error you got

Comment: Mykola, I use the exact command you posted:

javac my_package/my_program.java -cp commons-io.jar

The errors I get tell me that my other class files cannot be found.  "my_program.java" is my main class but I have 3 other *.java files that "my_program.java" depends on and one of those classes needs the "commons-io.jar" library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this and just used BufferedWriter and FileWriter instead. Was much easier and worked great.  Still don't know why Apache Commons IO wouldn't work for me...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
javac my_package/my_program.java -cp commons-io.jar
```

Comment: Thought I had it.  It compiled with out error but when I checked the folder no class files were created.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @typoknig - my thought is that you would do well to read the javac(1) "manual page" relevant to your platform; see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html

Comment: Yes, that is basically the same info that javac -help gives me, but following that as I understand it right now is not getting the job done for me, thus the question.  If my package was named "my_package" and my program was named "my_program" and all of my *.java files and my apacheCommonsIo.jar file were in a folder named "my_package" located directly on the (c:) drive what exactly do I need to type to type at the command line to make it all work?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Netbeans projects rely upon an ant file.
As a consequence, you can compile on command line by locating this ant file, and calling its correct target.

Take a look at [this forum message](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-8776.html).